# setting default gsettings for relocatable schema in /etc/dconf/db/local.d

Tags: gnome

Settings default gsettings for all my users with a `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/my-settings` file like this works fine:

```
[org/gnome/desktop/background]
picture-uri='file:///usr/local/share/backgrounds/wallpaper.jpg'
```

Now I'm trying to set a custom keybinding, which requires a `:PATH` (relocatable schema) like this:

```
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0]
name='keybinding-name'
command='my-command'
binding='my-keybinding'
```

Unfortunately, after running `dconf update`, the config values have not been set:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding command '<newname>'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding name '<newname>'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding binding '<newname>'
```

How can I properly set these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0]
```

works!